# InfluxDB - Inserting a tag value with space

Tags: graphite, influxdb

I am trying to insert a data into InfluxDB - graphite/tcp protocol using a template.

This gets inserted perfectly fine.

`us.west.cpu.load 100`

Sometimes **tag values** have some space it

ex: `us.west india.cpu.load 100`  --> does not get inserted

so,

`us.west\ india.cpu.load 100`     --> does not get inserted. escape does not work. HTTP API accepts this value.

`us."west india".cpu.load 100`     --> does not work

How to have this value get inserted? How should i escape these spaces?

Comment: Did you try encoding the space as %20 ?

Comment: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.9/write_protocols/write_syntax/#escaping-characters

Comment: @takirala, check what i have tried. \ would not work as the link you have shared is for line protocol. not for graphite

Comment: Are you sure that it is correct to send metrics with whitespace in its name via graphite protocol at all? According to this [blogpost](http://mingbowan.blogspot.ru/2012/08/enable-special-character-support-in.html) graphite does not support special characters in metric name

Answer (score 2):

You could try put "" before the space for your tag key.
Sample line protocol:

```
INSERT testMeasurement,testTagKey=us.west\ india.cpu.load\ 100 OTHERINFO
```

See more info [here](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/blob/master/tsdb/README.md).